# Separate X Screens with Unity and nvidia-current on 8600GTM

Tags: unity, nvidia, multiple-monitors

I used Lucid with gnome2 on this Laptop (Dell Vostro 1500, Nvidia 8600GT M, external Monitor via VGA with 1920x1080) and installed Oneiric because of using an SSD now.

I used to have 2 separate X Sessions because I want the Desktop not to change on my external Monitor when I switch Desktops on my Laptop Display.

Now on 11.10, I can set up everything with nvidia-settings (using nvidia-current but tried -updates and the 173 one too) but it won't work on the external Monitor.
It either shows a white Screen or (i think when I click into it) it shows the Wallpaper. The mouse remains as "x" like in low graphics mode.

I tried the xorg.conf from the 10.04 but that didn't work either.

Is this a known Problem/Bug? Or is this not supposed to work in Unity (problems with two Dashes maybe)?

Answer (score 1):

Have the same problem. It's not possible with Ubuntu 11.10 anymore, sorry. You can use TwinView which is the only option that partially works (unless you have screens with different refresh rates, for example, or if you need hardware acceleration on the second screen).

Comment: Thanks for the Answer, i am using the nouveau driver by the time because its not that lagging that much and there is no v-sync problem.